# Spring security - login 2 consecutive times behaviour

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I'm using spring security 3.2.5.RELEASE . I have this scenario:

create 2 different users.
login with the first and login again with the second before the session of user 1 expires (from the same browser)

Now a weird thing happens:

The Session is now related to the latter user, while the previous user's session was not expired (I mean no logout of the first user took place).

We are using a cutomized session registry for a tomcat cluster:

```
  @Override
    public void registerNewSession(String sessionId, Object principal) {

    Assert.hasText(
               sessionId,
               "SessionId required as per interface contract");
    Assert.notNull(
               principal,
               "Principal required as per interface contract");

    List<SessionInformation> allSessionsForAPrincipal = getAllSessions(
                                       principal,
                                       false);
    for (SessionInformation session : allSessionsForAPrincipal) {

        removeSessionInformation(session.getSessionId());
    }

    if (getSessionInformation(sessionId) != null) {

        removeSessionInformation(sessionId);
    }

    Element element = new Element(
                      sessionId, new SessionInformation(
                                    principal, sessionId, DateUtil.now()));
    sessionIds.put(element);
    }


 @Override
    public void removeSessionInformation(String sessionId) {

    Assert.hasText(
               sessionId,
               "SessionId required as per interface contract");

    SessionInformation info = getSessionInformation(sessionId);
    if (info != null) {

        info.expireNow();

        sessionIds.remove(sessionIds.get(info.getSessionId()));

        Element oldSession = new Element(
                         sessionId, info);
        oldSession.setTimeToLive(300);
        sessionIds.put(oldSession);
    }
    }
```

I would like the previous user's session to be invalidated before creating a new session for the new user. (Bear in mind the 2nd user's sessionId is the same as the previous)

EDIT:

this is the security.xml

```
<security:session-management
            session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />

<bean id="sas"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <constructor-arg ref="clusteredSessionRegistryImpl" />
                    <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
                    <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="false" />
                </bean>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <constructor-arg ref="clusteredSessionRegistryImpl" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

clusteredSessionRegistryImpl is the above session registry

Comment: Post some configuration... Basically you already have a session so a new one isn't created, you can configure session management but you haven't posted the configuration hence hard to say.

Comment: Please add which spring security version you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to configure is [Session Fixation Protection](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-session-fixation). Which is fairly simple just add the `session-fiction-protected` property to your `session-management` tag and specify `newSession` as the value. That will invalidate the old session at login and create a new one afterwards.

If that doesn't work add the [`SessionFixationProtectionStrategy`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/SessionFixationProtectionStrategy.java) to your `CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy`.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy">
   <property name="migrateSessionAttributes" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Make sure it comes before the `RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy` else a new session won't be registered.